# What is the best way to install Node js on OS X?

Tags: macos, install, homebrew

I currently have installed node and npm with the installer provided from their website. Although I have homebrew installed as well, and running `brew doctor` seems to complain about some files installed by the node js installer at /usr/local/include/.

Is installing node through homebrew a better way (e.g. easier to manage, less errors and warnings, etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the best way to install Node.js is to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which allows you to install and manage multiple versions of Node.

I use Homebrew for pretty much everything else, but Node is easier to use through nvm, since it doesn't use global folders - everything is in your home directory, and you can easily switch between Node versions.

To install (check the website for the latest version):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
```

There are some specific notes about OS X on the web site, please make sure to read through those, e.g. regarding the use of the `~/.bash_profile` file.

After that, the `nvm` function will allow you to specify which version of node to install and use. In the simplest case, you run

```
nvm install node
```

which will install the stable version of Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [volta](https://volta.sh/) to install node and npm

You need to put the volta directory (default `~/.volta/bin` on your path.

Then for node (and npm would be similar)

```
# install Node
volta install node

# start using Node
node
```

WHat volta does is put node etc into volta's directory.

volta also allows you to use different versions of node/npm and other downloaded javascript files in different projects.

The benefit here for homebrew users is that node and npm are not in `/usr/local/bin` and so `brew doctor` will not find a problem. volta can be installed via HomeBrew.